# Sending Mails from Django

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail

So, I am trying to send email from Django. And I am getting errors. I have exhausted ChatGPT, Google. And finally I am here for help. I have followed so many tutorials but no matter what I do I get this error.

```
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I have checked all my account details, password, other details 100's of time and all them should be what it is supposed to be.

Here is my settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND= 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS= True
EMAIL_PORT= 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'app password generated by google'
```

Here is the views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse

def simple_mail(request):
    send_mail(
              subject = 'test email 1',
              message = 'this is a test email',
              from_email = 'email@gmail.com',
              recipient_list = ['abc@gmail.com'],
              fail_silently=False,
                )
   return HttpResponse('OK')
```

The quota of free mails is not ended, well because I did not send any. Also, I am testing with localhost and internet is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the port u are using is wrong, it should be 465

change the settings like this.

EMAIL_PORT = 465